# How to count number of occurrences in a very big text for each keyword (regEx) of an array [JS]

Tags: javascript, regex, performance, count

This problem is mostly related to an optimization.

Suppose I have a very big text (const text = "...") and an big array of keywords (const keywords = ["one", "good days", "ar.i.t", ...]). You can notice that this keywords might be a single word, multiple words or any RegEx expresion. I need to count how many times each keyword (expression) occurs in the text.

My approach would be as follows:

```
const text = "..."
const keywords = [...]

keywords.forEach(keyword => {
    const re = new RegExp(keyword, "gi");
    const count = (text.match(re) || []).length;
})
```

The problem with this approach is that it is very slow (if text is big enough and array as well). I have to iterate through the entire text again and again until every keyword is checked. Could someone suggest an idea of an algorithm that would go through text only once and count occurence for every keyword, or any idea that could solve the problem faster.

Comment: As you need to count *each* word, there is no way to do this much more efficiently. Maybe precompiling the regexps is the only way. Also, since you are just looking for fixed strings, consider implelementing a non-regex solution, it might turn out faster.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor! I can't precompile the regex outside of the loop, because it is a new regex for every iteration (keyword), correct me if I'm wrong. Regarding second part, a non-regex solution should add significant improvement, but since I'm dealing with regex expressions as keywords, it's not a easy task.

Comment: You can, `const regexps = keywords.map(x => new RegExp(x, "gi")`

Comment: I think RegExp is already optimized for this scenario. I tried this approach, but it took longer.

Comment: Are you sure you want to count "one" as found in e. g. "gone"? And how big is _big_, and how big is _very big_? About how many of the keywords are RegEx?

Comment: Yes, "one" in "gone" should be counted. Big is roughly some thousands of keywords. Lastly, there are not so many regex expressions in keywords array, usually a few dozens.

Comment: Are there non-ASCII characters in the _very big_ (?) _text_?

Answer (score 0):

This might help slightly:

```
const str = 'this is a piece of text this is text this is text';

const countOcc = () => {
  const regex = /this/g, result, indices = [];
  while ((result = regex.exec(str))) {
    indices.push(result.index);
  }
  return indices.length
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Stephen. I tried some benchmarking using these 2 solutions, but they seems to be almost identical in performance.